# Angular 2/4 :Call method of a component from the root component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method "changeLanguage" in my appComponent for changing application language .. and I have many component like "folderComponent", "AdminComponent" etc.. 
So I would like when I click in radio button language (En, De), I refresh data of all component for translating in the current language .. 
**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   public language = 'fr';

  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    public folderService: FoldersService) {
    this.name = 'AppComponent';
    this.translate.addLangs(['de', 'fr']);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('../assets/i18n/fr');
    this.browserLang = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
    this.translate.use(this.browserLang.match(/de|fr/) ? '../assets/i18n/' + this.browserLang : 'fr');
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.credentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('credentials'));
  }

  changeLangueCCPD(language: string) {
    this.translate.use('../assets/i18n/' + language);
    ***// Here, how can I call any component for loading data with the current language ? Like call loadData() method of folder;component.ts***
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FoldersComponent } from './folders/folders.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, FoldersComponent, AdminComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing, NgbModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [AuthorizationGuard, FoldersService, AdminService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<span class="spanLabel"> 
<input class="option-input radio" type="radio" (click)="changeLangueCCPD('fr')" name="language" [(ngModel)]="language" value="fr" />
</span>

<span class="spanLabel"> 
<input class="option-input radio" type="radio" (click)="changeLangueCCPD('de')" name="language" [(ngModel)]="language" value="de" />
</span>
```

**folder.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-folders',
  templateUrl: './folders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folders.component.css'],
  providers: [AppComponent, {provide: Parent, useExisting: FoldersComponent}]
})
export class FoldersComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: any[];
  public language = 'fr';

  constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,private foldersService: FoldersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.loadData();
  }

  public loadData() {
     this.foldersService.getAllFolders().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = data;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to change language at runtime. In our project we just save value in the local storage and refresh the page. Does it fit your needs?

Comment: Yes like this, for the label I can translate it .. but the data I can't .. I will try  your solution, I think that it can work ... but How can I do you for refreshing page ? Use : window.location.refresh() ?

Comment: Just use window.location.reload();